# User-created list in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, list

```
<?php
include_once("blade/header.php");
?>

    <head>
        <title>User Profile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profileStyle.css">
    </head>
    <div class="leftpane">
        <h1>Favorite Movies</h1>
        <input type='text' id='idea' />
        <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />
        <script>
            document.getElementById("add").onclick  = function() {
                var node = document.createElement("Li");
                var text = document.getElementById("idea").value;
                var textnode=document.createTextNode(text);
                node.appendChild(textnode);
                document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);
                document.getElementById('idea').value=null;

            }
        </script>
        <ul id='list'></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="middlepane">
        <h1>Movie Lists<h1>

    </div>
    <div class="rightpane">
        <h1>Movie Reviews</h1></div>
    </div>

<?php
include_once("blade/footer.php");
?>
```

In the code you see above, it has a button with a text input that will allow me to make a temporary list. I am looking for a way so the user can make multiple lists for movie choices that will stay in their profile page permanently. I have not seen a way for a user to name each list, and also  categorize such as "Marvel" or "action" movies.

In the research that I have done, I only found ways to make it so there are preset options. I am trying to find results by looking up "php user-created lists." If anyone could at least provide key terms that would help me find what I am looking for, I would greatly appreciate it.

Other ways I found is by having the user input append to an sql database, similar to how login screens are done. The problem is that the php code would have to be updated in order to create a table for every user, which does not seem possible from what I have seen.

Comment: You need to decide whether this is going to be limited to the browser (in which case you can do it purely with Javascript) or whether you want to be able to save these lists to a database (in which case you'll need a server-side language like PHP and a database like MySQL or MariaDB). In any case, you should provide a mockup of how you want the front end to look, even if it doesn't work. That means if you want a way for the user to specify a new category, and delete a category, you need UI elements for those features.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each category to be created by the user, you could add a second text input and do something along the lines of:

```
if (*movie category already exists* && *input movie category* === *existing category*) {
  // place in this particular list category
}
```

And if you want it to persist across user sessions you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` without having to commit it to a database.

Is that how you mean?

Comment: Not without persisting to a database or storage. Without a database, anything the user does will be specific to their device.

Comment: Is there a front-end way of making user-created lists? Maybe it would be smarter for me to go about using javascript first and then integrate php

Comment: Yes, I believe that it would be smarter for me to create a front-end using javascript first @kmoser . Then it would be easier for me to tackle the backend stuff, rather than trying to work on the backend right now basically from scratch.

Comment: The front-end way is how you've done it in your post. If you want it to store only on the front-end, so the next time the user visits your site their list will still be there, use ```localStorage```.